# Folding paper strip and generate numbers while unfolding

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I have an assignment question that I am struggling with and need some direction to solve.
Suppose i have a strip of paper and i fold it from the center such that the left half goes behind the right half. Then i number the folded peices in sequence i get the numbers when i unfold as follows.
1 : 2

If i fold twice i get the numbers when unfolded as follows
1 : 4 : 3 : 2

if I fold thrice i get as follows
1 8 5 4 3 6 7 2

I want to generate the array of numbers when I fold it n times. so if i fold it for example 25 times i will get 2^25 numbers in similar sequence.

These are the observations i made

- the first and last numbers are always 1 and 2.
- the middle two numbers are always 4 and 3
- the number at index 1 is largest number and number at second last location is second largest number.
- It looks like a preorder traversal of binary search tree but I dont know how that helps.
- I tried to construct binary tree from the preorder and then convert it to inorder assuming that I can reverse this process to get the same series and I was wrong about it.

**EDIT** : For searching an element in this generated array I can do a sequential search which will be O(n) efficient. But I realise there has to be a much faster way to search for a number in this series.

I cannot do binary search because this is not sorted and there are over a billion numbers when 25+ foldings are done.

What kind of search tactics can i use to find a number and its index?

This was one of the reasons I wanted to convert it into a binary search tree which will have log(n) search efficiency.

**EDIT 2:** I tried the table folding algorithm as suggested by one of the answers and it is not memory efficient. I cannot store over a billion numbers in my memory so there has to be a way to find a numbers index without actually creating the array of numbers.

Comment: Why did the answers below get -1

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis There are widely varying opinions among users about what SO is: a community of people helping each other with programming problems, or an archive of high-quality Q&A's that may be useful to future users. Where people stand on this issue often explains their voting.

Comment: The sequence looked familiar, and it is indeed related to the one you get with bit reversal, so there may be algorithms there that you could adapt.

Comment: @m69 Oh! Bit reversal didnt occur to me yet. I have to explore those options. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the number of a fold without having to calculate the whole sequence by using bit-reversal (which reverses the binary representation of a number, so that e.g. `0001` becomes `1000`).

These are the sequences you get with bit reversal:

```
1 bit:    0  1
2 bits:   0  2  1  3
3 bits:   0  4  2  6  1  5  3  7
4 bits:   0  8  4 12  2 10  6 14  1  9  5 13  3 11  7 15
```

And these are the paper-folding sequences (counting from 0):

```
1 fold:   0  1
2 folds:  0  3  2  1
3 folds:  0  7  4  3  2  5  6  1
4 folds:  0 15  8  7  4 11 12  3  2 13 10  5  6  9 14  1
```

If you split the paper-folding sequences into even and odd numbers, you get:

```
          0
             1
```

```
          0     2
             3     1
```

```
          0     4     2     6
             7     3     5     1
```

```
          0     8     4    12     2    10     6    14
            15     7    11     3    13     5     9     1
```

You'll see that the paper-folding sequences are the same as the bit-reversal sequences, but with the first half (even numbers) interlaced with the reverse of the second half (odd numbers).

You'll also notice that each pair of adjacent even/odd numbers adds up to 2<sup>n</sup>-1 (where n is the number of folds), which means they are each other's inverse, and you can calculate one from the other using a bit-wise NOT.

So, to get the paper-folding number of fold x (counting from 0) of a strip folded n times:

> divide x by 2, perform bitwise NOT if x was odd, then bit-reverse (using n digits)

Example (folding 4 times):

```
fold   x/2    binary   inverted    bit-reversed    from 1

 0      0      0000                0000       0       1
 1      0      0000      1111      1111      15      16
 2      1      0001                1000       8       9
 3      1      0001      1110      0111       7       8
 4      2      0010                0100       4       5
 5      2      0010      1101      1011      11      12
 6      3      0011                1100      12      13
 7      3      0011      1100      0011       3       4
 8      4      0100                0010       2       3
 9      4      0100      1011      1101      13      14
10      5      0101                1010      10      11
11      5      0101      1010      0101       5       6
12      6      0110                0110       6       7
13      6      0110      1001      1001       9      10
14      7      0111                1110      14      15
15      7      0111      1000      0001       1       2
```

Example: billionth fold: (folding 30 times)

```
fold:            1,000,000,000
counting from 0:   999,999,999 (x is odd)
x/2:               499,999,999
binary:          011101110011010110010011111111 (30 digits)
bitwise NOT:     100010001100101001101100000000 (because x was odd)
bit-reversed:    000000001101100101001100010001
decimal:             3,560,209
counting from 1:     3,560,210
```

I don't speak Java, but something like this should do the trick:

```java
public static long foldIndex(int n, long x) { // counting from zero
    return Long.reverse((x & 1) == 0 ? x >>> 1 : ~(x >>> 1)) >>> (Long.SIZE - n);
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Just wonder why bit reversal can be used to solve this problem. (I have no knowledge about bit reversal before your solution).

Comment: @hk6279 This is the answer for which I first looked into bit-reversal; it describes how the sequence is built, and you can see how the symmetry would make it similar to the paper-folding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844446/gold-rader-bit-reversal-algorithm/31932631#31932631

Comment: Thanks to @MichaelMarkidis for pointing out some JavaScript-isms that were keeping my Java code from compiling.

Answer (score 6):

1st fold: 1 2

2nd fold: 1 4 3 2

3rd fold: 1 8 5 4 3 6 7 2

4th fold: 1 16 9 8 5 12 13 4 3 14 11 6 7 10 15 2

---

Generate table (with example to 4th fold)

> Imagine you have a nth fold paper and then unfold it.

1. Generate a table with size ( column = 1, row = 2^n ) and fill the column from down to up with values in ascending order

   > ```
   > 16
   > 15
   > 14
   > 13
   > 12
   > 11
   > 10
   > 9
   > 8
   > 7
   > 6
   > 5
   > 4
   > 3
   > 2
   > 1
   > ```
2. Resize the table to size (column = org. column*2, row = org. row / 2) recursively by sticking top x row to bottom x row from back to front

   > ```
   > 8  9
   > 7 10
   > 6 11
   > 5 12
   > 4 13
   > 3 14
   > 2 15
   > 1 16  
   >
   > 4 13 12  5
   > 3 14 11  6
   > 2 15 10  7
   > 1 16  9  8   
   >
   > 2 15 10  7  6 11 14  3
   > 1 16  9  8  5 12 13  4
   >
   > 1 16  9  8  5 12 13  4  3 14 11  6  7 10 15  2
   > ```
3. Read the final 1 row table from front to end as result

   > 1 16 9 8 5 12 13 4 3 14 11 6 7 10 15 2

---

The remaining work to you is to prove this work and then code it (I only test up to n=4 because I am lazy)

Comment: Your algorithm works. I posted an answer based on it. It's a clever approach.

Comment: That is some really clever thinking! I will try to work on a code for this algorithm and add it as an edit

Comment: The step one of your solution requires to store all numbers 2^n in an array. If i have 30 folds i have over a billion numbers, i cannot store that many numbers in memory.

Answer (score 2):

> Here'a an algorithm to find what index a number will be at after the
>   unfolding.

It keeps track of the coordinates of where your search number is moving to based on the folds. For example, if you are interested in 3 folds (n=3, `numFolds`) and you want to know where the number 7 will be (`searchNumber`), the algorithm runs as follows:

```
Initial State:
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1 

The 7 is at [1,7] - column 1, row 7 

Now, when we fold the top half down:
4 5
3 6
2 7
1 8

The 7 is at [2, 1] - column 2, row 2 

When we do the next fold the 7 does not move (hence the if (row > half) logic)

2 7 6 3
1 8 5 4

On the last fold:
1 8 5 4 3 6 7 2

The 7 is at [7, 1] - column 7, row 1 and the code will return 7.
```

```
public static long getIndexOfAfterFold (long numFolds, long searchNumber)
{
    long total = (long) Math.pow(2, numFolds);

    long [] coordsOfSearchNumber = new long [] {1, searchNumber};

    int iterations = 0;

    while (iterations < numFolds)
    {
        long half = total / 2;

        long row = coordsOfSearchNumber[1];

        // we are folding down
        if (row > half)
        {
            long newRow = (total - row) + 1;

            long col = coordsOfSearchNumber[0];

            long newFoldThickness = (long) Math.pow(2, iterations + 1);
            long newCol =  newFoldThickness - (col - 1);

            coordsOfSearchNumber[0] = newCol;
            coordsOfSearchNumber[1] = newRow;
        }

        total = total / 2;

        iterations++;
    }       
    return coordsOfSearchNumber[0];
}
```

**EDIT**: Converted the above code to use `long` instead on `int`.

**Notes**:

- It runs in O(n) time where n is the number of folds.
- Usage: `System.out.println(getIndexOfAfterFold(4, 13));`

### This code will give the list of all numbers after the folding

> **Note**: This is based on the answer supplied by @hk6279 (the table folding algorithm)

```
public static void unFold (int numFolds)
{
    int total = (int) Math.pow(2, numFolds);

    List<ArrayList<Integer>> table = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> (total);

    // populate the single column table
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(i + 1);
        table.add(list);
    }

    int iterations = 0;

    while (iterations < numFolds)
    {
        int half = table.size() / 2;

        // place the fold back on itself
        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> list = table.get(i);

            ArrayList<Integer> foldList = table.get(table.size() - (i + 1));

            // reverse the fold
            Collections.reverse(foldList);

            // add the fold to front
            list.addAll(foldList);
        }

        // remove the part we folded
        table.subList(half, table.size()).clear();

        iterations++;
    }
    System.out.println(table);
}
```

This is what n=5 looks like:

1, 32, 17, 16, 9, 24, 25, 8, 5, 28, 21, 12, 13, 20, 29, 4, 3, 30, 19, 14, 11, 22, 27, 6, 7, 26, 23, 10, 15, 18, 31, 2

Comment: This is a great working solution. Although i have the problem of storing all the numbers in an arraylist when folds go 30+ . I run out of memory.  Is there a way to find the item without actually creating the full array.?

Comment: That is an interesting proposal. I will have to think about that one. As far as the search complexity goes - it's actually somewhat similar to a binary search. I believe it is O(Log2(2^n)) -- log base 2 of 2 to the nth power. Here's my thinking: If you want to find where the 8 is in the 4 fold case (n=4), then you can find the 8 in 4 steps because you need 4 steps to get to the unfolded distribution. I can elaborate more in my answer.

Comment: Yes i realise that i can somehow "predict" where 8 is going to end up. It is sort of a modified binary search.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java, but this should be easy to port and works for arbitrary numbers of folds.  Idea's about the same as m69's, so I won't explain the logic myself.

```
#include <iostream>

size_t reverse(size_t n, int bits)
{
    size_t result = 0;
    size_t msb_value = 1 << (bits - 1);
    while (n)
    {
        if (n & 1) result |= msb_value;
        msb_value >>= 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}

struct Fold_Sequence
{
    Fold_Sequence(size_t folds) : folds_(folds), max_(1 << folds) { }

    size_t operator[](size_t i) const
    {
        size_t x = reverse((i / 2) % max_, folds_);
        return i & 1 ? (max_ - x - 1) : x;
    }

    size_t folds_, max_, i = 0;
};

int main()
{
    const size_t folds = 4;
    const unsigned num_parts = 1 << folds;
    Fold_Sequence seq{folds};
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < num_parts; ++j)
        std::cout << seq[j] + 1 << '\n';
}
```

I liked the elegance of hk6279's solution too, so I implemented it (also in C++, and I was too lazy to use a multidimensional array/`vector<vector<>>` and have to resize things carefully all the time, so it's inefficiently implemented using a `map` keyed on x,y coordinates):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

#define DBG(X) do { std::cout << X << '\n'; } while (false)

typedef std::pair<size_t, size_t> Coord;

struct matrix : std::map<Coord, size_t>
{
    matrix(size_t n)
      : y_size_(n)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            (*this)[{0, i}] = i;  // bottom left is 0,0; 0,1 is above
    }

    void fold()
    {
        size_t x_size_ = x_size();
        for (size_t y = y_size_ / 2; y < y_size_; ++y)
            for (size_t x = 0; x < x_size_; ++x)
                move(x, y, x_size_ * 2 - x - 1, y_size_ - y - 1);
        y_size_ /= 2;
    }

    void move(size_t from_x, size_t from_y, size_t to_x, size_t to_y)
    {
        DBG("move(" << from_x << ',' << from_y << " -> " << to_x << ',' << to_y
            << ") value " << ((*this)[{from_x, from_y}]));
        (*this)[{to_x, to_y}] = (*this)[{from_x, from_y}];
        erase({from_x, from_y});
    }

    size_t operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const
    {
        auto it = find({x, y});
        if (it != end()) return it->second;
        std::cerr << "m(" << x << ',' << y << ") doesn't exist\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t x_size() const { return size() / y_size_; }
    size_t y_size() const { return y_size_; }

    size_t y_size_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const matrix& m)
{
    for (size_t y = m.y_size_ - 1; y <= m.y_size_; --y)
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < m.x_size(); ++x)
            os << m(x, y) << ' ';
        os << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t n = 4;
    matrix m(1 << n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        m.fold();
        std::cout << i+1 << " folds ==> " << m.x_size() << 'x' << m.y_size()
            << " matrix:\n" << m << '\n';
    }
}
```